# Pacman does not install the most recent version of a package

Tags: manjaro, pacman

I'm trying to install Gradle on my Manjaro machine. I need to use it with Java 12, which implies that I need Gradle 5.6.x. [On this page](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/any/gradle/) it is said that version 5.6.2 is available, which is good news.

However, when I run

```
$ sudo pacman -S gradle
```

only version 5.5.1 gets installed, which seems to make no sense.
I have tried to remove the package, then upgrade my system with `-Syu` flag and then install it again but I still have the exact same problem.

Is there anything I can do to prevent this from happening ? Thanks

Comment: Use Arch Linux instead? That's the Arch Package Index you have linked to

Comment: Yeah, it seems that the issue is related to the fact that Manjaro uses its own repositories and they are not necessarily up to date with Arch repositories. I had never realized that they were not the same. This is actually fairly disappointing